# slideToggle and fadeToggle in JQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I want my menu to use a fadeToggle for tablets and desktop view (768px upwards) but I would like my nav to slideToggle on mobile (767px and below).

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    if($(window).width() >= 767){
    $('#toggleMenu').click( function(){
      $('ul.menu-nav').fadeToggle("1400");
    });    
    }        
});
```

but am unable to take things further.

Comment: Well, have you tried with `else` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, this will require jQuery UI:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggleMenu').click( function(){
        var toggleEffect = $(window).width() >= 767 ? "fade" : "slide";
        $('ul.menu-nav').toggle( toggleEffect, 1400 );
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="toggleMenu">Toggle Menu</a>
<ul class="menu-nav">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //Create a function for the two states.
    var toggleMenu = function() {
        if($(window).width() >= 767) {
            $('#toggleMenu').unbind('click').click( function(){
                $('ul.menu-nav').fadeToggle("1400");
            });    
        }
        else
        {
            //Smaller than 767
            $('#toggleMenu').unbind('click').click( function(){
                $('ul.menu-nav').slideToggle("1400");
            });   
        }
    };

    //Update if the window is resized and run the toggleMenu function.
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        toggleMenu();
    });
    toggleMenu();

});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/psvtr9ad/1/

**How it works:**

1. First, create a function named `toggleMenu` that contains the conditional logic.
2. The function will also unbind previous click events so that when called again, it will effectively "reset" the effect (between slide or fade toggle).
3. Then bind a window resize event so that if the browser window is resized, the function is run again and the correct effect function is used.
4. Lastly, call the function so it's executed on the page load.

Comment: The example above works like a dream .. ! Thank you very very much :)